# class file generated can't be decompiled

Tags: java, java-8

I am changing my previous question..
I am unable to decompile the generated class file if I use map function with stream .
I am using reflection to get a list of all classes in a package but the class can't be found.

The following code snippets show what i am using.

1)

```
List<Integer> associateIds = new ArrayList<>();
if (queryParameters.containsKey("associateIds")) {
    associateIds = Arrays.asList(queryParameters.getFirst("associateIds").split(",")).stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I tried removing map function, it works fine.

Comment: These are inner classes. They don’t have anything to do with Java-8 (unless you use a code transformer to convert Java-8 lambdas to pre Java-8 code).

Comment: ...or actually declare inner classes to be used with the Streams API.

Comment: If you want help, I suggest you delete this question, think about what you actually want to ask and *then* open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the new java 8 APIs.

Theses class files correspond to anonymous class your are creating:

```
new Consumer<DbUsrUsers>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(DbUsrUsers t) {
        teamMemberIds.add(t.getId());
    }
}
```